# автозаполнение полей формы (дата)

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

задача:  Автозаполнение поля типа date (HTML5), переданным значением типа Date.util(java)

```
function set_car(id, name, number, win, currKm, dInsurance, dView){

    $('#editRowCar').modal();
    $('#editRowCar').find('#id').val(id);
    $('#editRowCar').find('#name').val(name);
    $('#editRowCar').find('#number').val(number);
    $('#editRowCar').find('#win').val(win);
    $('#editRowCar').find('#currentKM').val(currKm);

    $('#editRowCar').find('#dateEndInsurance').val(dInsurance);  // как тут правильно поступить?
    $('#editRowCar').find('#dateEndView').val(dView);  // и тут

}
```

Comment: А причем тут java?

Comment: конвертация из java класса Date.util.     Вопрос решил своими силами, 

$('#dateEndInsurance').val(dInsurance.substr(0, 10));   -   через обрезку ненужных частей. спс за внимание.

Comment: Оформите как ответ ваше решение )